# Hover over parent element not child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger hover only when the mouse will be over parent `li` not child `ul` or `li`.
Here is my code which is not working

```
$('#menu-header-menu').on("mouseenter", ".menu-item:not(.menu-item .sub-menu)", function() {
 $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu" style="display: block;">
<li id="menu-item-1549" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1536 current_page_item menu-item-1549"><a href="myurl">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1627" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1627"><a href="myurl">Photo 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-1631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1631"><a href="myurl">Page1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1630" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1630"><a href="myurl">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1626" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1626"><a href="myurl">Photo 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-1633" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1633"><a href="myurl">Page1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1632"><a href="myurl">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1548" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1548"><a href="myurl">Project</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you share your html

Comment: Yes i am adding html now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always prevent propagation of events on child elements to accomplish that:

You can read more about event propagation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), but the general idea is that all events propagate up the DOM tree, so even that occurs on child element will also be triggered on each of its parents.

```js
$('.parent').on('mouseenter', function () {
  console.log('mouseenter');
});

$('.child').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.child > .child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your child events to bubble up to the parent, you would need to use `stopImmediatePropagation()` on the child event, in this case the hover. It might look something like this:

```
$('.child').on('hover',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stop event propagation, you can compare the element related to the event handler (`this`) with the element from which the event started bubbling (`ev.target`). If they are the same, you know that `this` is the first element hovered by the mouse cursor :

```js
$("#without-if").find("ul,li").hover(function (ev) {
  $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
$("#with-if").find("ul,li").hover(function (ev) {
  if (this === ev.target) {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
}
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}
ul {
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: yellow;
}
.hover {
  background: red;
}
#without-if * {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#with-if * {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="without-if"><ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>Without IF</div>
<div>Hover the small yellow square.</div>
<div id="with-if"><ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>With IF</div>
```